# Standard way to prove that groupoids are homotopy 1-types

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory

It is very well know that groupoids, considered as spaces via the nerve construction, are homotopy 1-types, i.e. aspherical. Here is a sketch of proof: Consider the canonical functor $f:C\rightarrow \pi_1(C)$ for a category $C$ and its fundamental groupoid $\pi_1(C)$. The Quillen-fiber based at some object $Y$, i.e. the slice category $Y\backslash f$, is the universal covering category of $C$. If $C=G$ is a groupoid, then $\pi_1(G)$ is $G$ itself and $f$ is essentially the identity. It is not hard to see that the Quillen-fiber in this case has a terminal object and thus is contractible, which proves the statement.

Is this the standard way to prove that groupoids have vanishing higher homotopy groups?

Comment: How about this? It is well-known that the nerve of a groupoid is a Kan complex, and that the nerve of any category is 2-coskeletal. But 2-coskeletal Kan complexes must have trivial higher homotopy groups.

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "the standard way "?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A low tech-argument:

-a groupoid is a disjoint union of connected groupoids

-the nerve construction preserves disjoint unions

-a connected groupoid is equivalent to a group, and thus its nerve is aspherical.

Comment: Ah well, I know that a group being aspherical is even more standard than a groupoid being aspherical. But in the spirit of the question you should also give a nice argument for this case. ;)

Comment: A good construction of the classifying space BG of a group
comes with a construction of a universal cover EG >--> BG
with the discrete group G as fiber.  Therefore BG = K(G,1).